# Expression for power of a natural number in terms of binomial coefficients

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, summation

Is there a general expression for the pth power of a natural number k in terms of binomial coefficients?

I found this identity in a high-school text, which was obtained by simply equating coefficients:

$k^3 = 6 \binom{k}{3} + 6 \binom{k}{2} + \binom{k}{1}$

I would like to know the general expression for $k^p$ in terms of binomial coefficients.

I would also appreciate it if someone could tell me the names of texts which might cover such expressions, and what they can be used for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The coefficients $6,6$ and $1$ in that expansion are closely related to [Stirling numbers of the second kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind). There is an identity

$$x^n=\sum_k{n\brace k}x^{\underline k}=\sum_k{n\brace k}x(x-1)(x-2)\dots(x-k+1)\;,$$

which in the case $x=m\in\Bbb N$ becomes

$$m^n=\sum_k{n\brace k}\frac{m!}{(m-k)!}=\sum_k{n\brace k}k!\binom{m}k\;,$$

so that the coefficients are the numbers $\displaystyle k!{n\brace k}$. I didn’t bother to specify the range of $k$, because it’s implicitly determined by the Stirling numbers themselves: for $n>0$, the only values of $k$ for which $\displaystyle{n\brace k}\ne0$ are $k=1,\dots,n$.

A good place to learn about such things is the excellent book [*Concrete Mathematics*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201558025), by Graham, Knuth, & Patashnik.

Comment: Thank you. 
While trying to find a general expression for sums of powers using the telescoping method, I noticed: $$n^2-2\sum_{k=1}^nk+n=0$$
$$n^3-3 \sum_{k=1}^nk^2+3\sum_{k=1}^nk-n=0 $$
and so on. I just finished high school, so with the very modest knowledge of the Pascal numbers that I have, I obtained: 
$$n^p=\sum_{i=1}^p \left( \binom{p}{i}(-1)^{i+1}\sum_{k=1}^nk^{p-i}\right)$$
However, I did not prove it. I also saw an expression using the Riemann/Hurwitz Zeta functions.

But clearly, I have a lot more ground to cover, and the book you recommended seems to be the right place to start.

Comment: @Shaaz: You want $n^p$ in terms of $\binom{n}{i}$ or $\binom{p}{i}$? The former is what you seemed to have asked in the question (and answered nicely in the answer here), but the latter is what your above comment talks about.

Comment: @Aryabhata: Yes, my original question was well answered, and the intention of my comment was to see if anyone could offer anything else that might be relevant. How else could $n^p$ be expressed in terms of $\binom{p}{i}$?

Comment: @Shaaz: Perhaps you should ask a separate question. I believe there are multiple ways though. The $p^{th}$ derivative of $e^{nx}$ is $n^p e^{nx}$, and you can write $e^{nx}$ as a product(in different ways) and use Leibniz's general product rule for differentiating the product. $\binom{p}{i}$ show up, and then set $x= 0$ to get an identity.

Comment: @Shaaz: You’re welcome. Judging from the mathematics that you’re doing and what you’ve said about your background, I think that you’ll find *Concrete Mathematics* both fascinating and useful.

Answer (score 4):

See the Wikipedia under [Binomial coefficients as a basis for the space of polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Binomial_coefficients_as_a_basis_for_the_space_of_polynomials).

In your particular case, and using the notation of the Wikipedia article, from which I am quoting formulas,
$$
t^{d} = \sum_{k=0}^d a_k \binom{t}{k}, 
$$
where
$$
a_k = \sum_{i=0}^k (-1)^{k-i} \binom{k}{i} i^d.
$$

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the wikipedia article, it contains a lot of relevant information - it seems that I completely overlooked it.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
Also, from Knuth CM-book:
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{rcll}
\ds{n^{\underline{1}}} & \ds{=} & \ds{n,} &  \ds{n = n^{\underline{1}}}
\\
\ds{n^{\underline{2}}} & \ds{=} & \ds{n\pars{n - 1},} & \ds{n^{2} = n^{\underline{1}} + n^{\underline{2}}}
\\
\ds{n^{\underline{3}}} & \ds{=} & \ds{n\pars{n - 1}\pars{n - 2},} & \ds{n^{3} = n^{\underline{1}} + 3n^{\underline{2}} +
n^{\underline{3}}}
\\
\ds{\vdots} & \ds{\vdots} & \ds{\vdots} & \ds{\vdots} 
\end{array}\right.
$$
For instance $\ds{\pars{~sum\ \mbox{looks like an}\ integration~}}$:
\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\sum_{n = 1}^{N}k^{2}} =
\sum_{k = 1}^{N}\pars{k^{\underline{1}} + k^{\underline{2}}} =
\pars{{1 \over 2}\,k^{\underline{2}} +
{1 \over 3}k^{\underline{3}}}_{1}^{N + 1}
\\[5mm] = &\
\bracks{{1 \over 2}\,\pars{N + 1}^{\underline{2}} +
{1 \over 3}\pars{N + 1}^{\underline{3}}}\ -\
\underbrace{\pars{{1 \over 2}\,1^{\underline{2}} +
{1 \over 3}1^{\underline{3}}}}_{\ds{= 0}}
\\ = &\
{1 \over 2}\pars{N + 1}N +
{1 \over 3}\pars{N + 1}N\pars{N - 1}
\\[5mm] = &\
\pars{N + 1}N\bracks{{1 \over 2} +
{1 \over 3}\pars{N - 1}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\bbx{N\pars{N + 1}\pars{2N + 1} \over 6} \\ &
\end{align}