# Combinatorial express of n^3

Tags: combinatorics

I know following expression

$$n = {n\choose 1 } $$

$$n^2 = {n\choose 2 } + {n+1\choose 2 }$$

but how about $n^3 = $?

Are there simple expression?

Comment: likely related to stirling's number of one kind or another.

Comment: This question has an answer: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/358165/expression-for-power-of-a-natural-number-in-terms-of-binomial-coefficients

Comment: Thank you. Steve,,, I got the answer for my questions from your link..

Comment: The next step is $$n^3=\binom{n}{3}+4\binom{n+1}{3}+\binom{n+2}{3}.$$ There is a way to write $n^k$ as sums of binomials $\binom{n}{\ell}$, and then from there one may combine these binomials to get it in the form $a\binom{n}{k}+b\binom{n+1}{k}+c\binom{n+2}{k}+\cdots$ using the recursive formula for binomial coefficients. This new form is distinct from the form discussed in that link, but I am undecided if that's sufficient reason to reopen this question. If I can think of a good way to characterize the $a,b,c,\cdots$ and give a combinatorial proof then I will argue for reopening.